# Bundle product problem

Tags: magento2, product, bundled-product

I hope you are doing good. My problem is that when I'm creating a bundle product on luma theme, product's first option is not selectable, meanwhile on my custom theme product's options are selectable, but qty is not increasing.

Any idea how can I fix it?

[image]